# Does Sunny Day Affect Flare Blitz?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I was reading on Smogon the other day that Sunny Day affected moves like Flare Blitz, although it didn't specify why (I assumed it had something to do with power). I looked up both moves on Bulbapedia, and I didn't see anything there, so can anyone confirm that in the 6th gen Sunny Day affects anything other than pokemon who have Growth (+ATK/SPA)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sunny Day](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sunny_Day_(move)) causes the weather effect of [intense sunlight](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Intense_sunlight) which alters the way some things work for a few turns:

> - **Increases the power of Fire-type moves by 50%.**
> - Decreases the power of Water-type moves by 50%.
> - Allows Solar Beam to be used instantly.
> - From Generation V onward, causes Growth to raise Attack and Special Attack two stages each.
> - Activates the following Abilities: Chlorophyll, Dry Skin, Flower Gift, Forecast, Leaf Guard, Solar Power.
>
>   - Causes Forecast to change Castform to its Sunny Form.
>   - In Generation V onward, causes Flower Gift to change Cherrim to its Sunshine Form.
> - In Generation IV, changes Cherrim to its Sunshine Form.
> - Guarantees Harvest will restore a held Berry.
> - Changes Weather Ball to a Fire-type move and doubles its power.
> - Prevents Pokémon from becoming frozen.
> - Causes Moonlight, Synthesis, and Morning Sun to recover ⅔ of max HP (twice the normal amount in Generation II).
> - Lowers accuracy of Thunder and Hurricane to 50%.

As [Flare Blitz](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flare_Blitz_(move)) is a fire typed move, its power is increased by 50% by the effects of Sunny Day.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this'll be good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sunny Day increases the damage of fire-type moves by 50%. Since Flare Blitz is a fire-type move, it is also affected by Sunny Day.

To expand the answer, I'll list effects of Sunny Day which i know below:

- It increases the damage of fire-type moves by 50%
- It lowers the damage of water-type moves by 50%
- Thunder and Hurricane have 50% accuracy instead of 70%
- Moonlight, Synthesis and Morning Sun heal 66.7% instead of 50%
- Solar Beam doesn't have to charge and is used immediately
- Growth increases both stats by 2, instead of only 1.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer! This'll be useful. :)